# Recommendations for a web app to manage beta testers

Tags: webapp-rec, recommendations

I'm running a beta test, and I need some way of managing my beta testers. Are there any apps out there that will allow me to:

- Add a number of users
- Send them messages both individually and in bulk
- Provide a method for them to send me feedback and discuss suggestions among themselves

I've not found anything that fits the bill so far.

Comment: How is the "beta-testers" use-case distinct from other mailing-list needs? Everything you have above sounds like standard email scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Feedback and suggestions can be implemented using [UserVoice](http://uservoice.com/)
[Google Groups](http://groups.google.com) will give you all the other stuff you need.

Comment: I really like UserVoice. I noticed that Spotify is using http://getsatisfaction.com/, which looks to be a very similar service. UserVoice will give you an open forum for free, but I guess you probably want a private one for beta testing, which is a service both sites charge for.

Answer (score 0):

I use gMail for communication with a beta-group.

To maintain privacy, the mail is sent to myself (`<address>+betagroup@<host>.com`) while individual addresses are hidden by entering the group-name as a `bcc:` (gMail then fills in the fields with all of the individual address; hence the bcc:)

This does NOT allow for inter-group communication, however.

I've been meaning to switch over to a private google-group for.... a year now? heh.